# how to create an InputStream from a Document or Node

Tags: java, xml, xstream

How can I create an InputStream object from a XML Document or Node object to be used in xstream?  I need to replace the ??? with some meaningful code.  Thanks.

```
Document doc = getDocument();
InputStream is = ???;
MyObject obj = (MyObject) xstream.fromXML(is);
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(doc);
Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

Comment: you used the 1st line of code in the last line. the middle lines did not do anything if u check it ...

Comment: The first line used ByteArrayOUTPUTStream while the last used ByteArrayINPUTStream. Futhermore, outputStream declared in the first line is used as a param to StreamResult.

Comment: but fomsource doesn't accept document. casting doc to Node doesn't work as well. any suggestions?

Comment: Document is a subinterface of Node, so you should be able to use Document as is. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Java without any Third Party Libraries, you can create `InputStream` using below code:

```
/*
 * Convert a w3c dom node to a InputStream
 */
private InputStream nodeToInputStream(Node node) throws TransformerException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    t.transform(new DOMSource(node), outputTarget);
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it: Adapt the `Document` to a [Source](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html) with [DOMSource](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMSource.html). Create a [StreamResult](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html#StreamResult()) to adapt a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). Use a [Transformer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) from [TransformerFactory.newTransformer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer()) to copy across the data. Retrieve your `byte[]` and stream with [ByteArrayInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

Putting the code together is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 3):

```
 public static InputStream document2InputStream(Document document)    throws IOException {
      ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      OutputFormat outputFormat = new OutputFormat(document);
      XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(outputStream, outputFormat);
      serializer.serialize(document);
      return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
 }
```

This works if you are using apache Xerces implementation, you can also set format parameter with the output format.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static InputStream documentToPrettyInputStream(Document doc) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    XMLWriter xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(outputStream, OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint());
    xmlWriter.write(doc);
    xmlWriter.close();

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

    return inputStream;
}
```

If you happen to use DOM4j and you need to print it pretty!