# How to convert Document object to Input Source?

Tags: java, xml, xerces, jdom

I am having a XML document objecy created on the fly. I need to validate it against Schema. I am using xerces 2. I have set features for the parser.Now i need to parse to validate the XML.

For this i need to call "parser.parse()". But parse() method takes "InputSource" as parameter. But i have Document object. How do i convert this Document object to "InputSource" for passing it to parse() method.

Can anybody help.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream docOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
((XmlDocument)domDocument).write(docOutputStream);
ByteArrayInputStream docInputStream = new
ByteArrayInputStream(docOutputStream.toByteArray());
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(docInputStream);
parser.parse(inputSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this question to convert the Document to an InputStream: [how to create an InputStream from a Document or Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865039/how-to-create-an-inputstream-from-a-document-or-node)

Then use [InputSource(java.io.InputStream byteStream)](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#InputSource(java.io.InputStream)) to wrap that with an InputSource.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to to this:

- Create a javax.xml.validation.Schema instance based on your schema resources.
- Create a javax.xml.validation.Validator from the schema instance
- validate your DOM document using the validator and a javax.xml.transfrom.dom.DOMSource